# Continue call on FaceTime in MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, facetime

When I make a call through FaceTime in my MacBook, I can switch to my iPhone and continue the call from there by just clicking on the top green bar that appears with the caller name. But can I do the opposite and switch back to my MacBook?

What I'm looking forward to understand is, how can I:

1. Start a call from FaceTime in my MacBook
2. Pickup the call in my iPhone
3. And then pickup again in my MacBook

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to transfer an ongoing call over FaceTime from your iPhone to your MacBook. Let's double-check that you have things set up correctly.

Obviously, you'll need to use the same Apple ID on both devices and, based on your description, I assume you've got this all set. Now make sure you do the following:

1. On your iPhone, go to Settings
2. Swipe up and tap on FaceTime
3. Now check what options you have listed/ticked for where you can be reached by FaceTime.
4. Make sure the Apple ID / iCloud account you've used on your MacBook for FaceTime is listed **and** ticked:

   - If it's not listed, tap on **Add an Email...** to add it
   - If it is listed but not ticked, then tap on it to enable it
5. Exit Settings

This should rectify the issue.

Let me know how you go.

Comment: But _what_ do you do on your Mac to transfer it? I'm not him, but all the time I pick up calls on my Mac and transfer them to my phone, but I've never figured out how to transfer them back.

Comment: hi @Monomeeth, I don't know if I explained myself well but the situation rovr138 is describing is exactly what I'm looking to understand. I want to make a call trough my MacBook > then pickup in iPhone > and then pickup in MacBook again

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for editing the question to clarify. I can't say I've ever done what you're wanting to do, but I'll do some testing later today to see if I can get it to work that way. Hopefully in the meantime someone may come up with a definitive answer one way or the other.

Comment: Yeah I'm not actually sure that there is any way to transfer the call from the iPhone to the Mac, even if everything is all configured as you describe in this answer.